# Do antiparticles exhibit different chemical properties?

Tags: atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, antimatter

In my physics class today. My teacher mentioned anti-helium and since I had never heard of anti-atoms (if you get what I mean by that) just antiparticles, this made me think: If we could produce anti-helium in our world without it being annihilated by helium, would it still exhibit the same chemical properties? (i.e. floating upwards or making anti-isotopes)

Comment: The standard hypothesis is that anti-atoms would have the same chemical properties, but there are, so far, next to no experimental confirmations of that. There are, however, some experiments (e.g. at CERN) that are trying to test this hypothesis.

Comment: Just want to point out.   Anti-helium wouldn't need to hit a helium to annihilate.   The positrons around anti-helium would interact with electrons in any near-by atom and the anti-protons and anti-neutrons in the anti-nucleus would evaporate in contact with any proton or neutron, not just a helium nuclei.

Answer (score 0):

No. Chemical reactions and some physical properties are determined by the electron structure for normal matter, and symmetrically the same for positron in antimatter. So chemical reactions between antimatter would appear similar in every respect as normal matter behaves.

Of course mixing matter with antimatter leads to a much different result, with the reaction not being chemical, but rather annihilation.

Comment: Three words for you, Charge Parity and Time.

Comment: @Aron: care to elaborate? I think many here believe this answer is correct.

Comment: @Gert my point is that only CPT is preserved. We know certain reactions break CP/CT symmetry, so it is completely possible for chemical reactions to be slightly different (they would of course be similar to a few 9s).